# Localized iOS App - Obtain Device Language (not App Language)

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have an localized iOS App from which I want to obtain the device language (**not the app language**). The following sample app is localized in English and German. The current app language is German.

Here I want to obtain english, since that's the device language (see next screenshot).
[image]

**Device Language Settings:**
[image]

**App Language Settings:** (shouldn't be considered for obtaining device language)
[image]

Is there any API I could use to retrieve the device language?

Code of Sample App:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Hello, world")
            Text("Locale.preferredLanguages:\n\(Locale.preferredLanguages.joined(separator: ", "))")
            Text("Locale.current:\n\(Locale.current.language.languageCode?.identifier ?? "")")
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
To obtain the device language is a product management requirement to derive next steps in the app localization process.

Comment: Can you explain, in the question, why you need the device language instead of the app language? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question (it's a product management requirement).